# PHP 5.3 Zend - not seeing how a method is being called

Tags: php, methods, properties

I am experiencing a problem I've not encountered before.  In a class for a project (which I believe is based on `Zend` Framework), I have a method called `fetchKey()`, the full class name is

```
//found in file Orm.class.php
MyCompany_Core_Orm extends MyCompany_Core_Db (which extends MyCompany_Core)
```

Inside of fetchKey, there is the following line:

```
$value = $this->$property;
```

By using ORM SQL logging (logQueries=1), I'm able to narrow down that this line causes SQL queries to happen; with it, the queries happen, and without it they don't.

`$property` is a string, I've checked, there IS no actual attribute by that string name.  In fact, `$property` could be any number of values based on the db relationships.  But the key problem: I'm honestly baffled how an as-yet unknown function call could happen *when a method is merely referenced*.  Is there an aspect of error reporting or use of `__call` or `__get` that I'm missing?  Appreciate help!

For reference the function is posted below, if that helps with familiarity:

```
public function fetchKey($property)
{
    //NOTE: I've checked and this logical block doesn't happen
    if (self::getOrmProxy() && method_exists(self::getOrmProxy(), __FUNCTION__)) {
        $proxyArguments = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::getOrmProxy(), __FUNCTION__), $proxyArguments);
    }

    $savedPropertyValue = null;
    $propertyExists = false;
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
        $propertyExists = true;
        $savedPropertyValue = $this->$property;
        unset($this->$property);
    }

    $value = $this->$property;

    if ($propertyExists === true) {
        $this->$property = $savedPropertyValue;
    } else {
        unset($this->$property);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: You could start by searching for the __get method through a class hierarchy.

Comment: so __get would be invoked on a non-existent attribute (no () parentheses at the end) as well as a non-existent method/function?

Comment: There signatures are `__get($name)` and `__call($name, array $args)`, see [php.net docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

Answer (score 0):

The function `property_exist()` cannot detect properties that are magically accessible using `get()` method
But this function can found even private property.